# Does TransactionScope flow across async continuations without the original context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, transactionscope

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC5 application and I have the following situation:

1. Async controller method calls custom async method 1+ times, each Task object being stored successively in a List
2. Each custom async method call establishes its own top-level TransactionScope with TransactionScopeAsyncFlow.Enabled
3. Each custom async method call performs transactional work, then awaits DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
4. While this is occurring, the controller method performs its own transactional work within its own unrelated TransactionScope, then awaits Task.WhenAll()

The question arises from using ConfigureAwait(false) when awaiting DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(). Each call to the custom async method starts in the controller method's ASP.NET request context but I don't see any need to recapture it when SaveChangesAsync() returns EXCEPT if it's going to mess up the current transaction. This is important because if an unrecoverable exception occurs in the controller method before I await Task.WhenAll, I need to cancel the async Tasks within a catch block, which means instead of awaiting Task.WhenAll() I'm forced to use the blocking method Task.WaitAll(), which I'm pretty sure will deadlock if the async Tasks are trying to recapture the original request context.

Sorry if this is a repeat question. I did quite a bit of searching and couldn't get a clear answer. Feel free to tell me this is bad programming or whatever, just at least suggest an alternative and leave my mom out of it. Thanks!

Comment: `Each custom async method call establishes its own top-level TransactionScope` sounds like it's *not* top level but nested because it all happens on the same thread.

Comment: "I'm forced to use the blocking method Task.WaitAll" Hm, I did not understand why. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The async method calls use TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, which creates a new top-level transaction, no?

Comment: As for Task.WaitAll, the await keyword cannot be used within a catch block so I can't "await Task.WhenAll()" to get the results from the async methods

Comment: You can rewrite the method so that you don't need to await in catch.; OK, RequiresNew creates new transactions but only one of them is active on any given thread/callcontext. This is likely going to mess up the scope nesting somehow, maybe non-deterministically depending on what operation completes first. This exceeds my abilities, though. Just feels wrong.

Comment: Ok cool, these are things I didn't know. I'll do a bit more research, thanks.